# Запись в txt цикла массива php

Tags: php, json

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть массив

```
{"status":"ok","orders":[{"orderid":"32977","number":"32977","ordercode":"","ordername":"\u041e\u0431\u043c\u0435\u043d \u0432 1\u0441","ordersource":false,"clientid":"13354","clientname":"\u0421\u0430\u043c\u043e\u0445\u0438\u043d \u0412\u043b\u0430\u0434\u0438\u0441\u043b\u0430\u0432","clientemail":"samokhin.contrust@gmail.com","clientphone":"380660785767","clientaddress":"","managerid":"0","cdate":"2018-01-17 10:04:36","dateto":"","deliveriID":"0","deliverinote":"","deliveriprice":"0.00","paymentid":"0","storagetoid":"0","storagetoexternalid":"","sum":"0.00","margin":"0.00","sumbase":"0.00","currency":"UAH","statusid":"133","statusname":"\u0417\u0430\u0434\u0430\u0447\u0430 \u0432\u044b\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0430","statuscolor":"#949494","workflowid":"19","workflowname":"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u044f \u0437\u0430\u0434\u0430\u0447\u0430","contractorid":"0","contractorname":null,"customfields":[],"products":[],"clientcompany":"Contrust","clientcode":"28452925","weight":0,"gabarite":0},{"orderid":"32978","number":"32978","ordercode":"","ordername":"\u0417\u0430\u0434\u0430\u0447\u0430 \u0432\u044b\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0430","ordersource":false,"clientid":"13354","clientname":"\u0421\u0430\u043c\u043e\u0445\u0438\u043d \u0412\u043b\u0430\u0434\u0438\u0441\u043b\u0430\u0432","clientemail":"234","clientphone":"234","clientaddress":"","managerid":"0","cdate":"2018-01-17 09:46:12","dateto":"","deliveriID":"0","deliverinote":"","deliveriprice":"0.00","paymentid":"0","storagetoid":"0","storagetoexternalid":"","sum":"0.00","margin":"0.00","sumbase":"0.00","currency":"UAH","statusid":"133","statusname":"\u0417\u0430\u0434\u0430\u0447\u0430 \u0432\u044b\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0430","statuscolor":"#949494","workflowid":"19","workflowname":"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u044f \u0437\u0430\u0434\u0430\u0447\u0430","contractorid":"0","contractorname":null,"customfields":[],"products":[],"clientcompany":"Contrust","clientcode":"28452925","weight":0,"gabarite":0}]}
```

Есть код с помощью которого запускаем цикл массивов и выводим его.

```
foreach ($array['orders'] as $item)
{
    echo $item['orderid'];
}
```

Не могу записать в json все эти orderid

```
file_put_contents(
    'chat.json', 
    json_encode(['command' => $item['orderid']], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) 
);
```

Так записывается только один orderid, но не все.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно собрать сначала полный массив идентификаторов и его уже записывать в файл.

```
$myArray = [
    'command' => $orderIDsArray, //массив из всех идентификаторов
];

json_encode($myArray) // где $myArray заранее собранный массив.
```

а если вы пытаетесь сделать это в цикле, то получите много кодированных строк, а не цельный json.

В файле вы видите только 1 идентификатор из-за того, что не правильно используете file_put_contents в этих целях. Для добавления новых строк в файл и чтобы не перетирать уже существующие эту функцию стоит использовать с флагом FILE_APPEND

Подробнее в документации [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php)

По запросу пример кода с выборкой и записью:

```
$json = ''; // тут json который необходимо обработать
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$orders = [];
$file = 'my_file.txt';

foreach ($data['orders'] as $order) {
    echo $order['orderid'] . '<br>'; // если нужно посмотреть
    $orders[] = $order['orderid'];
}

file_put_contents ($file, implode(PHP_EOL , $orders)); // вместо PHP_EOL можно поставить любой нужный знак для удобства чтения
```

Comment: Подскажите, можно код с записью в json файл? А лучше запись в txt файл этих orderid. Спасибо.

Comment: На самом деле полностью не понимая задачи от и до я не могу дать полностью верный ответ. потому что я вижу у вас какой-то вывод через echo, дальше вы пытаетесь что-то записать в файл но массив не представлен, а есть его json представление. опишите задачу полнее для возможности полноценно вам ответить. 

Например: есть у меня json - его нужно конвертировать в массив, вывести на экран такие то данные, а затем сделать массив с такой структурой и записать его в файл

Comment: echo это просто мне, можно не обращать внимания. Я по апи получаю массив, который я скидывал. После циклом проверяю все orderid. Все эти orderid мне нужно записать в файл txt. Просто по списку все orderid.

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, смотрю

Comment: Поправьте пожалуйста ответ, что бы каждый orderid был с новой строки. Спасибо.

Comment: Так же не могу orderid завернуть в ссылку

Comment: Ссылка должна быть в текстовом файле уже? или когда echo в цикле делается? Ответ обновил

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо за помощь